# Creating a table in a read-only replica cluster in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I wonder if I misunderstood the read-only replica setup somehow. I can create a table in the read replica node with YSQL ... should that really be possible?

My cluster-config looks like this :

```
version: 2
replication_info {
  live_replicas {
    num_replicas: 3
    placement_blocks {
      cloud_info {
        placement_cloud: "cloud1"
        placement_region: "datacenter1"
        placement_zone: "rack1"
      }
      min_num_replicas: 1
    }
    placement_uuid: "285d2309-d7aa-42e8-9d36-bc820316215d"
  }
  read_replicas {
    num_replicas: 1
    placement_blocks {
      cloud_info {
        placement_cloud: "cloud1"
        placement_region: "datacenter1"
        placement_zone: "rack1"
      }
      min_num_replicas: 1
    }
    placement_uuid: "285d2309-dada-dada-dada-bc820316215d"
  }
}
cluster_uuid: "dc9bafde-dda6-4098-aa2f-f4cc3404033f"
```

I expected ysqlsh to scream and shout at me when I tried to create a table on the node that belongs to the replica placement UUID ... but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

DDL and writes are rerouted to the primary cluster.
You're never really "connected to a node" as a user (as an administrator you can obviously work with individual nodes). YugabyteDB spreads out the leader and follower tablets of tables and indexes as evenly as it can over the entire read-write cluster. This means that from your YSQL session, you communicate with all leader tablets involved in the query, which are distributed over the cluster nodes randomly.